# Processing a form on the same page

Tags: php, html, forms

So, I've been messing with this for a day now and I've read a lot tutorials and even posts on stackoverflow. I know it's possible to have all your php form processing steps on the same page as your form, but for some reason, my form won't send an email. Any help?

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">

<form method="post"  action="index.php" enctype="text/plain" name="emailform">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="First Name or Alias"><br>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"><br>
<textarea name="message" rows="10" size="50" placeholder="Placeholder Text."></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit &rarr;" name="submit" class="button round">
</form>

<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = $_POST['email'];
$to = 'email@address.com'; //set to the default email address
$subject = 'Hello';
$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";


$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

if($_POST['submit']) {               
mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers);  //mail sends it to the SMTP server side which sends the email
echo "<p>Your message has been sent!</p>";
} 

else { 
echo "<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>"; 
} 
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Check the logs, are there any errors?

Comment: If you're attempting to run everything on the same page and your code file isn't named `index.php`, then do `action=""` You also need to wrap your PHP in a conditional statement, PHP on top and HTML below that.

Comment: Also, remove `if($_POST['submit']) {` ,  --- then above your opening `<?php`  replace with `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` and add an extra closing brace `}`, because as it stands, your conditional statement is executing whatever is inside `if($_POST['submit']){...}`

Comment: Also, remove `enctype="text/plain"` that's a biggie right there.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `enctype="text/plain"` that's a main factor.

Plus, you also need to check if fields were left empty using (*if*)[`empty()`](http://php.net/empty).

Not doing so, you may receive emails that either do not contain the user's email, name, message or a combination of all.

Assuming this file is called `index.php` if not, use `action=""`

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">

<form method="post" action="index.php"  name="emailform">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="First Name or Alias"><br>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"><br>
<textarea name="message" rows="10" size="50" placeholder="Placeholder Text."></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit &rarr;" name="submit" class="button round">
</form>

<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = $_POST['email'];

$to = 'email@example.com'; //set to the default email address

$subject = 'Hello';
$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email'])  && !empty($_POST['message']) ){

// check if mail was sent
if(mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)){  //mail sends it to the SMTP server side which sends the email
    echo "<p>Your message has been sent!</p>";
    } 

else { 
    echo "<p>Mail was not sent. Check your logs.</p>"; 
    }

}

else { 
    echo "<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>"; 
}

?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {               
  if(empty($_POST[name]) && empty($_POST[email]) && empty($_POST[message])){
    echo 'Fields cannot be empty';
} else{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $to = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = "Hello";
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
    mail ($to, $subject, $body);
}

}else{
  echo "<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>"; 
}
```